# How do I take a screenshot that includes the moon using camera mode in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

There's a camera mode in Terraria (F1) that takes snapshots and allows you to capture a user-defined frame beyond what's viewable on the screen. Whenever I take screenshots this way, the moon doesn't show up (or the weather... rain does, but gray haziness doesn't). How do I use camera mode to capture the weather as well?

Comment: If the camera mode takes away the HUD you could use another screenshot software like the one built into Steam.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I’ve been using the Steam one, but what’s nice about the in-game one is that it can capture beyond the visible screen for bigger builds.

Comment: Perhaps there is a 3rd party software package available for what you’re after. There are plenty for editing the world, so it wouldn’t surprise me if there is one for doing what you’re after.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot capture the sun, moon or certain weather effects with the in-game camera mode. In the camera settings, there is a toggle for entities, but this only includes "living" things like the player, NPCs, monsters, and pets. You can also disable the entire background. The only way I can think of where you could make this partially work is if you took an image with the in-game camera, then took one with Steam (F12), and then edited the moon/sun into the image afterward. For weather this wouldn't work though. You could theoretically take multiple Steam screenshots and edit them together for that.